# Square root in a finite field of characteristic 2.

Tags: abstract-algebra

suppose F is a finite field of characteristic 2. 
I know that the map $x \to x^2$ is a automorphism over F. so every element in F is a square. But how do we find the square root?

Thanks

Comment: Well its a finite field, so there aren't too many options.

Comment: @ElliotG, finite can still be of high order. Is finding square root proportional to the characteristic?

Comment: yeah my comment was not a solution. for some reason i thought OP had a particular field in mind. to be fair they did not even bother to state their question though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F$ has $q=2^m$ elements.
If $a\in F$, then $a = a^q = (a^{2^{m-1}})^2$.

Comment: Shorter, smoother, and slicker than what I was cooking up.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplicative structure of the field of $q$ elements is the same as that of the roots of $x^q - x$, i.e., $0$ and $e^\frac{k2\pi i}{q-1}$ ($0 \leq k < q-1$) . If it has characteristic $2$ then $q = 2^m$. The square root of $0$ is $0$, and the square root of $e^\frac{k2\pi i}{q-1}$ is $e^\frac{\ell2\pi i}{q-1}$ where $\ell = \frac{k}2$ mod $q-1$; since $q-1$ is odd, this is a well-defined operation.

Comment: Is there any chance that you can clarify what you mean by your first sentence ? I'm having trouble to understand.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Are you familiar with the identification of finite field elements with roots of $x^q-x$?